# How to use two LIKE conditions?

Tags: oracle, sql-like

I need to find students with A and M in their first name but that do not have an a and m in their last name. This is my query but for some reason it keeps displaying last names that have M's... What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT (firstname || ' ' || lastname) AS "FullName"
  FROM A5
 WHERE Lower(FirstName) LIKE '%a%m%' 
   AND Lower(LastName) NOT LIKE '%a%m%'
ORDER BY LastName,
         FirstName
```

Comment: a and m together in both first and last name? Also, are you looking for case sensitive comparison? Your query has lower case comparison but you say last names having upper case M's are displayed (which is obvious)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE` clause should be:

```
WHERE (Lower(FirstName) LIKE '%a%m%'
OR Lower(FirstName) LIKE '%m%a%')
AND Lower(LastName) NOT LIKE '%a%'
AND Lower(LastName) NOT LIKE '%m%'
```

You were only including cases where FirstName had an a *followed by* an m. Similarly, you were only excluding the cases where LastName had both an a AND an m, where the a comes before the m.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (firstname || ' ' || lastname) AS "FullName"
FROM A5
WHERE (lower(firstname) like '%a%' and lower(firstname) like '%m%') and ((lower(lastname) like '%a%' and lower(lastname) not like '%m%') or (lower(lastname) not like '%a%' and lower(lastname) like '%m%') )
ORDER BY LastName,FirstName
```

Try this.

Comment: @Ana Mar whats wrong with this query? It should address your problem perfectly. Let me know the failure cases..